# How to remove unwanted contacts on Skype

Tags: privacy, contacts, user-accounts, skype

I have a big privacy problem with unwanted address book contacts showed in skype for windows desktop.

What I did is:

- Logged in with the skype account (a work account) on my personal Android smartphone;
- Removed contacts syncing from Skype app on Android smartphone;
- Logged out from this account on Android smartphone;
- Opened Skype for Windows desktop computer and a lot of contacts from my personal contacts list are showed on "contacts all" tab. It is showed as: "John Smith is an address book contact", and it shows also the account name if clicking on the profile picture (i.e. john.smith)

This is very annoying because this is a workplace skype account and I do not want my boss and my colleagues to see all my personal contact list on the company computer.

Is there a way to see the address book and to delete these contacts?

If I select the contact and right-click on the blue area around it, I do not see the option remove contact from the list menu.

Any useful tips are very welcome!

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the missing `Remove from Contacts` list item?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't because have not enough reputation on the forum

Comment: What is strange is that this issue affects only my contacts. The regular contacts have the "remove" option.

Comment: Interesting. Comment a link to the picture using [Imgur](http://imgur.com/) and I will insert it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and sorry for the late answer. I am figuring out what is happening with the Skype customer service. I think I do not need the screenshot for the moment. I will post the solution once I have found it!

Answer (score 1):

After contacting the Skype customer service, I figured out that the contacts I see are not really contacts because they have not shared the details yet, but "contacts suggestions", as stated the customer service advisor making a comparison with Facebook. Anyway, to me, this does not mean that Skype can take contacts from the address book in my Android phone and matching them in its database if I do not want to. However there is no way to dismiss or ignore those "contact suggestions", probably breaching personal privacy, as instead has Facebook (extending the comparison started by Skype advisor).

Luckily I managed to find a workaround, it is not perfect but at least it works. I erased all the contacts on my Android phone address book; I entered again with this account on Skype on the phone; when the screen asking to copy contacts from the address book appeared, I dismissed it by clicking on the cross and the "back" button; I opened settings; I went to "contacts": contacts were synced by default, I selected "do not copy contacts".
If I select again "copy contacts" with the empty address book, contact suggestions reappear even if contacts are no longer there (so matching still works and don't understand why if address book is empty).

A little oddity: I have another smartphone with the latest Android version. I obviously tried to deselect the option "copy contacts" in skype app, but it remains stuck on it. No way. In this case I am luckier because the latest Android version always asks permissions for apps to access data and by default they are disabled. I continuously receive the pop up "allow Skype to access contacts?" And I always answer "deny".

Hope being useful to someone.

Answer (score -1):

Click on the unwanted contact in your contacts list, then click on the name at the top.  After that click view in local address book.  Once you do that a window will open with information about that contact, then click the three dots and delete.  Restart skype and they are cleared.